# Why does my Matlab code not work correctly?

Tags: matlab, debugging

My code

```
    b(abs(b(1:3:length(b))) > 0.75) = 0.75
```

What it's supposed to do:

```
    b1 = b(1:3:end);
    b1(abs(b1)>0.75) = 0.75;
    b(1:3:end) = b1;
```

How are these two not the same?

Comment: The first line of the 3 line exmaple does nothing.

Comment: Yes it does. I want every third position in the vector.

Comment: No it doesnt. It doesnt asign enything nor does save the result anywhere. Most likely you mean `b1=b(1:3:end)`

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot a part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexing part `b(1:3:end)` returns a short vector of zeros and ones, so will only change the `i`-th entry of `b` (for `i` in the first third-ish of `b`) to `0.75` if the absolute value of the `3*i + 1`-th entry is greater than `0.75`.

For example:

```
b = [-0.684; 0.941; 0.914; -0.029; 0.6; -0.716; -0.156; 0.831; 0.584; 0.919];
b_index = abs(b(1:3:length(b)))>0.75
```

would return

```
b_index =

     0
     0
     0
     1
```

and `b(b_index) = 0.75` would change the 4th entry of `b` to `0.75`.

One way of doing this as a one-liner is

```
b(1:3:end) = b(1:3:end).*(abs(b(1:3:end))<=0.75)) + 0.75*((b(1:3:end)>0.75));
```

but I think the three-liner is a bit clearer.